# AWS S3 .NET SDK

Tags: ssl, mono, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity3D, and have try to use S3 .NET SDK. But keep getting below error:

```
TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff80092012
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.validateCertificates (Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection certificates)
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.ProcessAsTls1 ()
```

My javascript code:

```c#
function Start()
{
    client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(Conf.AWSAccessKey, Conf.AWSSecretKey);

    var response : ListBucketsResponse = client.ListBuckets();
}
```

I have searched a whole day and probably found the reason:

It turns out that Mono installs with no root certs, so by default Mono refuses to trust any SSL-protected web services.  [The Mono Security FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Security) has a couple suggestions for how to handle the issue."

I have tried below methods:

1. [Reference](http://flkoliv.com/index.php?q=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5tb25vLXByb2plY3QuY29tL1VzaW5nVHJ1c3RlZFJvb3RzUmVzcGVjdGZ1bGx5)

   ```
   mcs am1.cs

   mono am1.exe https://www.amazonaws.com
   ```

   When I run compiled am1.exe, it gives me a lot of exception errors
2. Use the mozroots.exe tool to download and install all Mozilla's root certificates.

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.6.7\lib\mono\1.0>mozroots --import --machine --sync
   ```

   Although the output said the certs have successfully imported. But in Unity3D it still prompts "Invalid certificate received from server"

I have been working on this the whole day and can't get it solved, hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

**0x80092012** occurs when the certificate could not be verified for revocation.

Since version 2.8, Mono will default to **X509RevocationMode.NoCheck** unless the **MONO_X509_REVOCATION_MODE** environment variable is set (in this case it will check for CRLs inside the certificate stores).

I don't know how recent is your version of Unity3D wrt Mono itself. However you should be able to use [ICertificatePolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.icertificatepolicy.aspx) or [ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx) to work around this issue. Simply disregard the **0x80092012** error code if it comes from a certificate issued to Amazon.

Comment: what's the first release that includes this?

Comment: @knocte I don't remember, but it was before Sept 2011 ;-) To find it you'll need to track the change on github (when `MONO_X509_REVOCATION_MODE` was introduced) and check the release branches that contains that commit.

Comment: thanks, https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/231f4decce353eb21f4eaf0d6ed0ee7b1ef6268b so 2.8 includes this

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TrustAllCertificatePolicy : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy
{
     public TrustAllCertificatePolicy() {}
     public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint sp, 
         X509Certificate cert,
         WebRequest req, 
         int problem)
     {
        return true;
     }
}
```

So before establishing HTTPS connection (either via WebRequest, WebServices or other) to       remote server just call:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new TrustAllCertificatePolicy();
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP for in mono, you need download and install the Mozilla's root certificates with the user www-data

```
chown www-data /var/www/
sudo -u www-data mozroots --import --sync
```